# Swift - Left hand side operand with question mark

Tags: swift

```
var i: Int?
i? = 1
print(i)
```

I thought the above code would print `1` but actually it printed `nil`. As I guess, `?` makes program skip `i? = 1` when `i` is `nil`.

Even if I replace `i? = 1` with `i? += 1`, it still can run and print `nil`

```
var i: Int?
i? += 1
print(i)
```

`i?` is `Int?` and `1` is `Int` but somehow `+` operator still works on 2 different types and passed compiler check.

Could anyone help me explain what happened? It's perfect if we can have an official document which talks about this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Optional Chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) as in `foo?.bar = 123`.

If you change the type to `Int`, the compiler will complain:

```swift
var i: Int
i? = 1 // Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Int'
```

From the linked reference above:

> The assignment is part of the optional chaining, which means none of the code on the right-hand side of the `=` operator is evaluated.

Comment: I read this section but I think it's not Optional Chaining. How can you explain `i? += 1`?

Comment: The same way. If `i` is `nil`, `i? += 1` will not evaluate the assignment. If on the other hand it is say `3`, it will set `i` to `4`.

Comment: As I said in my question, `i?` is `Int?` and `1` is `Int`. Normally if you use `+` operator on 2 different types, compiler will throw error. But in this case, it didn't.

Comment: `i` is `Int?`. `i?` is optional chaining. Everything around optionals involves syntactic sugar. When you do `let x: Int? = 4`, you're really saying `let x: Optional<Int> = Optional.some(4)`. But that would be cumbersome to write so the compiler does that for you.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you misunderstood. In short, my question is how Int? and Int can be used with + operator.

Comment: Due to the optional chaining. `i? += 1` will only succeed if `i` is not `nil`. If that's the case, you have an `Int` to the right of `?`.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me. The problem is not on the right of `?`. It's on the left. `i?` is `Int?` and `i` is `Int`. In normal case, when you write `Int? + Int`, compiler will throw an error immediately. But in this case, it doesn't. I know optional chaining and I also read Optional Chaining in Swift doc but I don't see any example explain for this behavior.

Comment: Think of it as `if let i = i { i + 3 }`. Inside the if you are adding two `Int`s, not `Int?` and `Int`.

Comment: Maybe but I'm thinking that `i? += i` means `i?.func+=`(calling function of `+=` on variable `i?`) because operators in Swift are functions. So it makes senses when `i` is nil and the method isn't called. How do you think about it?

Comment: No. It's the same function. `public static func += (lhs: inout Int, rhs: Int)`. The compiler handles this whole optional chaining syntactic sugar. In a rather inaccurate view, it's similar to short circuit in boolean evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info on **Swift basics** [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html).

In your example, `i` is an optional Int. To assign a value to it, you

```swift
var i: Int?

i = 1
```

If you want to calculate a new value from it, you could use optional binding with either `guard let` or `if let` (the `x` variable in the example below) or you could force unwrap it (as with the `i` variable in the `print()` statement below).

```swift
var i: Int?

i = 1

if let x = i {
    i = x + 1
}

print(i!)
```